# Waiting for 2016

Tags: code-golf

### Task

Constantly having to check on television, or the time on your computer to see if its 2016 is a tedious task. Being programmers, we should be able to automate this task. Write a program that will output `2016` when the system time hits Friday, January 01, 2016 00:00:00. or rather `1451624400000` ms since midnight January 1, 1970.

### Input

There will be no input to your program.

### Output

Your program will output `2016` to STDOUT or the equivalent when the system time hits `1451624400000`. The maximum allowed delay is 1 second or `1000` ms. If your program is started after `1451624400000`, it should not output anything (an empty string is fine) and terminate normally.

### Rules

- Your code must be a full program, not just a function.
- You can assume your program will be started after midnight January 1, 1970.
- Your program should be able to detect 2016 within a second of it occurring.
- Your program should terminate after outputting `2016`.
- If your program is started after midnight January 1, 2016, it should not produce any output, or an empty string, and should terminate normally.

### Scoring

To keep with the trend of shortcomings in 2015, this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Many of [Legen… wait for it…](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64870/legen-wait-for-it) and [Is it Christmas?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/is-it-christmas) solutions seems to be reusable here...

Comment: I was actually looking at the [Legen… wait for it…](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64870/legen-wait-for-it?lq=1) challenge. The reason I didn't consider this a duplicate is that this one is easier in that you can hard code the date you're waiting for, so that'll hope allow shortcuts in the code, and also, there isn't a guaranteed output if your code starts after `2016`.

Comment: So when the program is run prior to 2016-01-01, it should wait until 2016 then print and exit? That is, if this were to hypothetically be run in 1986, it would have to continue to run for 30 years?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If it run anytime after Jan 1, 1970 and before Jan 1, 2016, it should run until midnight Jan 1, 2016, print `2016` and then exit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
WnJ2016.d3=hZ)IZJ
```

This is rather simple.

- `J2016`: assign `J = 2016`
- `.d3`: gets current year
- `WnJ2016.d3`: while current year is not 2016
- `=hZ`: increment `Z`, which starts at 0
- `)`: end the loop
- `IZJ`: print `J` (2016) if `Z` is not zero, i.e. the loop was run at least once

Comment: An alternative to `2016`: `C\ߠ`

Comment: @LegionMammal978 One character less, but would take more bytes. Also, Pyth uses ISO-8859-1.

Comment: `ߠ` uses 2 bytes, so it would cancel out.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yeah, but then `2016` is still more readable. Also I don't think you can do `ߠ` in ISO-8859-1

Comment: It works on the online interpreter for me.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <s>53</s> 49 bytes

```
a:=UnixTime[]<1451606400;If[a,While@a;Print@2016]
```

<s>Not entirely sure if it works. Will have to wait for another 9 hours...</s>

Comment: LOL and what... just imagine... WHAT if it doesn't work?? :O

Comment: You can change the date on your computer. Also, you can come to Finland where it's only 2 more hours ;-)